# python 3.4.1 itertools documentation syntax lambda( x,_:r*x*(1-x)

Tags: python, lambda, python-itertools

The python 3.4.1 Functional Programming documentation provides examples of itertools.  It is section 10.1 under the Functional Programming section 10.0.  There is a lambda function defined with the syntax: (The value of r is set elsewhere in the example.)

```
lambda(x,_:r*x*(1-x))
```

I have not seen the `_` syntax as above.  Can someone explain the `_` please.  In Erlang the `_` would match a "don't care".  I don't know what it does here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`_` is a variable like any other. The name `_` is typically used for variables we don't care about, though this is just a convention; the value isn't automatically discarded or anything.